# Join Linq The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq code like:

```cs
var model = await (from a in _context.Mfemployees
                    join b in _context.Mfclients on a.MfemployeeClientCode equals b.MfclientCode into ab
                    from x in ab.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join c in _context.Mujls on new { a.MfemployeeGroup, a.MfemployeeEmploymentLevel } equals new { MujlGroup = c.MujlGroup, MujlLevel = c.MujlLevel }
                    select new ExportPartiesDTO
                    {
                        MFEMPLOYEEGroup = a.MfemployeeGroup,
                        MFEMPLOYEEEmployeeCode = a.MfemployeeEmployeeCode ?? "",
                        MFEMPLOYEEEmploymentDate = a.MfemployeeEmploymentDate,
                        MFCLIENTName = x.MfclientName ?? "",
                        MFCLIENTSurname = x.MfclientSurname ?? "",
                        MFCLIENTPhone = x.MfclientPhone ?? "",
                        MFCLIENTHP = x.MfclientHp ?? "",
                        MFCLIENTEmail = x.MfclientEmail ?? ""
                    }).ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

I still don't get it, why the `join` word on this line

```cs
join c in _context.Mujls on new { a.MfemployeeGroup, a.MfemployeeEmploymentLevel } equals new { MujlGroup = c.MujlGroup, MujlLevel = c.MujlLevel }
```

is still incorrect. `The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to join.`?

I already check the datatype, all datatype are the same. String datatype.
Can someone help me to explain, why the error is happen to my linq code?

Really appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean to say `a.MfemployeeGroup equals c.MujlGroup and a.MfemployeeEmploymentLevel equals c.MujlLevel`?

Comment: @Sweeper, yes. Correct.

Comment: Does this work? `join c in _context.Mujls on new { MujlGroup = a.MfemployeeGroup, MujlLevel = a.MfemployeeEmploymentLevel } equals new { MujlGroup = c.MujlGroup, MujlLevel = c.MujlLevel }` Make sure that both types have the same properties.

Comment: @YongShun, `join` word still error which is I already type on my question. both has the same properties, all strings.

Comment: Mean that even you add `MujlGroup` and `MujlLevel` property in the first anonymous object, you still encounter the same issue?

Comment: And please share the entity classes for `Mfemployee` and `Mujl` in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
var model = await (from a in _context.Mfemployees
                    join b in _context.Mfclients on a.MfemployeeClientCode equals b.MfclientCode into ab
                    from x in ab.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join c in _context.Mujls on new { MujlGroup = a.MfemployeeGroup, MujlLevel = a.MfemployeeEmploymentLevel } equals new { MujlGroup = c.MujlGroup, MujlLevel = c.MujlLevel }
                    select new ExportPartiesDTO
                    {
                        MFEMPLOYEEGroup = a.MfemployeeGroup,
                        MFEMPLOYEEEmployeeCode = a.MfemployeeEmployeeCode ?? "",
                        MFEMPLOYEEEmploymentDate = a.MfemployeeEmploymentDate,
                        MFCLIENTName = x.MfclientName ?? "",
                        MFCLIENTSurname = x.MfclientSurname ?? "",
                        MFCLIENTPhone = x.MfclientPhone ?? "",
                        MFCLIENTHP = x.MfclientHp ?? "",
                        MFCLIENTEmail = x.MfclientEmail ?? ""
                    }).ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Please check on `join c in _context.Mujls` line.
I made some changes on this line.